# A matrix inverse identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For matrices $A, B$, I would like to show and understand the intuition behind the following identity
$$
(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - (A+B)^{-1} B A^{-1}
$$
assuming the inverses exist.

Comment: To prove it just multiply by $A+B$

Comment: ...from the left

Answer (score 2):

$$(A+B)\big [ A^{-1} - (A+B)^{-1} B A^{-1}\big ] =I + BA^{-1}-BA^{-1}=I$$

Thus  $$(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - (A+B)^{-1} B A^{-1}$$

The intuition behind it is probably $$ \frac {1}{a+b} = \frac {1}{a} -\frac {1}{a+b}\frac {b}{a}$$

where a and b are real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$$ A^{-1}-(A+B)^{-1}BA^{-1} = (I-(A+B)^{-1}B)A^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1}(A+B-B)A^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1}AA^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1} $$